# Holoviews/Datashaded map overlay not displaying

Tags: python, holoviews, holoviz, holoviz-panel

I am using the code below to get a Panel dashboard with a dropdown select box, a histogram and a map.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, rasterize, shade
import panel as pn
from holoviews.element.tiles import OSM
import hvplot.pandas

    
df = pd.read_parquet('cleanedFiles/AllMNO.parquet')
mno = pn.widgets.Select(options=df['mnc'].unique().tolist())

@pn.depends(mno)
def mnoStats(operator):
    return'### Operator {} has {} samples'.format(operator, len(df[df['mnc'] == operator]))

@pn.depends(mno)
def plotMap(mno):
    opts = dict(width=700, height=300, tools=['hover'])
    tiles = OSM().opts(alpha=0.4, xaxis=None, yaxis=None)
    points = hv.Points(df[df['mnc'] == mno], ['latitude', 'longitude'])
    rasterized = shade(rasterize(points, x_sampling=1, y_sampling=1)).opts(**opts)
    return tiles*rasterized


def plotHist(df):
    return df.hvplot.hist(y='rsrp', by='mnc', bins=20)

pn.Row(pn.Column(pn.WidgetBox('## Ofcom scanner data', mno, mnoStats)),
       pn.Column(plotHist(df))).servable()
pn.Row(plotMap).servable()
```

The dropdown selector and histogram appear as expected, however I get a 'blocky' image for the map as below. I wanted to get the locations (lat/longs) of the measurements each coloured / datashaded by the signal level denoted by the column 'rsrp'

[image: Panel Dashboard]

Please advice how this can be corrected.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This is a pretty complex question, where the answer depends on the interaction of your code and your data, but we don't have your data! Please see this guide to creating a [mre]; ideally, create a new, dummy dataset using code that fully demonstrates your issue but is easy for us to work with and doesn't involve downloading a huge file. It looks like a dataframe built off a list of random lat/lons would do the trick - can you reformat your question to provide a full example?

Answer (score 1):

According to the holoviews docs, [`hv.rasterize`](http://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.operation.html?highlight=rasterize#holoviews.operation.datashader.rasterize) is a high-level resampling interface and passes parameters to several internal methods:

> [**`holoviews.core.operation.Operation`**](http://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.core.html#holoviews.core.operation.Operation): `group, input_ranges`
>
> [**`holoviews.operation.datashader.LinkableOperation`**](http://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.operation.html?highlight=rasterize#holoviews.operation.datashader.LinkableOperation): `link_inputs`
>
> [**`holoviews.operation.datashader.ResamplingOperation`**](http://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.operation.html?highlight=rasterize#holoviews.operation.datashader.ResamplingOperation): `dynamic, streams, expand, height, width, x_range, y_range, x_sampling, y_sampling, target, element_type, precompute`
>
> [**`holoviews.operation.datashader.AggregationOperation`**](http://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.operation.html?highlight=rasterize#holoviews.operation.datashader.AggregationOperation): `vdim_prefix`

Based on this, it looks like your arguments x_sampling and y_sampling are passed to [`ResamplingOperation`](http://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.operation.html?highlight=rasterize#holoviews.operation.datashader.ResamplingOperation), which are described:

> **`x_sampling = param.Number(allow_None=True, inclusive_bounds=(True, True), label=’X sampling’)`**
> Specifies the smallest allowed sampling interval along the x axis.
>
> **`y_sampling = param.Number(allow_None=True, inclusive_bounds=(True, True), label=’Y sampling’)`**
> Specifies the smallest allowed sampling interval along the y axis.

So, I'd guess that the issue is that providing the arguments `x_sampling=1, y_sampling=1` to `rasterize` has the effect of aggregating all of your data to 1 degree, or approximately 110 km/70 mile blocks, which is causing the blockiness in your figure. Changing these parameters to a smaller value, such as 0.1 or smaller, should resolve the issue, as long as your data itself has sufficient resolution.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. This worked. I wanted to know how did you get to the correlation between 1 degree corresponds to 110km/70mile blocks?

Comment: That’s a very rough approximation that is close-ish (right to within a few km) for most mid latitudes on earth. Haha don’t use that for anything precise, but it’s useful for ballparking. See https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml (or a million other resources) for calculating distances on earth more precisely based on pairs of latitudes and longitudes.